# Java Cannot load a custom font from file and set JTextArea's font to it

Tags: java, fonts

So I'm trying to make a simple application, and I got a window appearing. The problem is that I require some special font, which I doubt would be installed on the user's OS, so I've got to load it from a file.

I've read countless articles and I've been stuck on this for quite a while and I'm not sure if the font isn't being loaded or it's not registering. I've also gotten confused with the type of "Stream" to use, because countless tries with `InputStream`, `FileInputStream` and `BufferStream` have lead to nothing.

The font **is** being copied to the output directory. This is my project structure

```
<packages-with-classes>
fonts
 -> gameFont.ttf
```

This is the code I'm using

```
    displayArea = new JTextArea();
    displayArea.setEditable(false);

    //FONT to give graphics (plz help me)
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = null;
    try {
        //ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        /*Font initFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/gameFont.ttf") );
        Font fontBase = initFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);*/
        Font gameFnt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fonts/gameFont.ttf")).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 12f);
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(gameFnt);
        displayArea.setFont(gameFnt);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a really really huge headache, I got it working :)

Here's the code if anyone else is stuck on the same problem:

```
InputStream fontStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/gameFont.ttf");
try {
    Font gameFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,fontStream);
    gameFont=gameFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14);
    displayArea.setFont(gameFont);
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```